# Summernote - Custom Button on multiple Editor Instances

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, summernote

i have a custom Button in Summernote, it's working as expected.
Problem is, that it works on all instantiated Editors at the same time.

To reconstruct the issue better:
I have a button, when i click it, a new Editor is initialized.
I'm making 2 Editors.
I click 1 of them and add Text to it via my custom button -> works.

I click the second Instance and add Text to it via my custom button:
The text gets added to both editors.

```
var HelloButton = function (context) {
        var ui = $.summernote.ui;

        // create button
        var button = ui.button({
            contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Hello',
            tooltip: 'hello',
            click: function () {
                   context.invoke('editor.insertText', myCat);
                });
            }
        });

        return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
    }
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you instantiating your summer note editors ? are you creating them by class id or name html attribute ? making each input distinct should resolve your issue.

```
<div class ="form-group">
<label for="inputA"> Input A </label>
<textarea class="textarea-inputA" id="inputA" name="inputA" />
<span validationfor="inputA">
</div>



<div class ="form-group">
<label for="inputB"> Input B </label>
<textarea class="textarea-inputA" id="inputB" name="inputB" />
<span validationfor="inputB">
</div>
```

then call summernote() on each selection how you were activating the controls previously.

Comment: Thank you!
This could be my issue, currently all .text-classes will become a summernote editor. I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: Thank you, i added an id to all summernote-fields and this solved my issue!
edit: Somehow the upvote isn't working, or it will take a while, i don't know.